# New passport and can I travel instantly?

Tags: uk, passports, europe

Im a British citizen and receiving my new passport tomorrow. It had 2 months left on the passport but had to renew because it wasnt enough to travel to europe. Are those 2 months added onto my new passport? Im seeing places say it does and other say it doesnt.

If it doesnt add any months. Can I travel instantly? Well the next day? Im receiving the british adult passport. Thank you.

Comment: I don't hold a British passport but to the extent that months are added to it, it would be by making it valid a little bit longer. I have never seen or heard of a passport with a start of validity date in the future. Also, two months isn't much, a little overlap is normal and expected, why are you so concerned about getting time added to the new passport?

Comment: I believe ICAO-compliant passports cannot be valid for more than 10 years

Comment: Until 2018, the UK issued passports that were valid longer than 10 years. For new passports this should no longer happen. For the Schengen Area in general: [Entry requirements - Germany travel advice - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/germany/entry-requirements): *valid for at least 3 months after the day you plan to leave Germany, or any other Schengen country ; The 3 months you need when leaving a country must be within 10 years of the passport issue date.*

Answer (score 2):

You can travel as soon as you receive your passport.

Assuming they are still adding months at the end, then your new passport might have an expiry date in March 2032, rather than January 2032. Although it will be valid as far as the UK is concerned, other countries may treat it as only being valid for 10 years, to some date in January 2032.

Comment: See the comment on the question by Mark Johnson, the extra time at the end of the passport should no longer happen.